# How can I restyle email using Stylish in Thunderbird (from eBay)?

Tags: email, thunderbird, styles, stylish

eBay changed their layout so it's one item per line (essentially) instead of several in a grid arrangement.  This applies to automatically sent emails with the results of my standing searches. Given the change, I have to do a lot of scrolling now where a grid arrangement would allow me to see most of the results sent by default in a glance per email.  As I get like 40 or so per day, that results in a lot of extra scrolling!

The emails are in html format so CSS rules should apply, but when I write CSS rules they do not seem to affect these emails -- I've tried the usual crazy rules to verify any effect, such as setting, body { color: red !important; }

I am not trying to restyle the Chrome or UI of Thunderbird (once again) but restyle various parts of emails from a particular sender.  Thanks for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Give the Stationery plugin a try.  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/stationery/?src=search

You can make a template for these particular emails, and the plugin lets you choose to work under the hood.

I'm sorry this is not a Stylish solution as you requested....

---

Thanks for explaining more about what you're after.  I have a couple of new ideas for you.

Forward these emails to a gmail account, where you would use a script to put these emails automatically into a spreadsheet as they arrive, which would hopefully be easier for you to scan visually.

Similar, but with IFFT (If This Then That).

Use a different thunderbird add-on called Import Export Tools.  This idea isn't automatic, however.  You highlight the relevant email messages and Export to your desired format.  You could experiment with the different formats provided to see which one works best.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I do have Stylish already installed, but now I can look at Stationery too.  The unfortunate aspect is that each plugin added slows the whole system, and may have unintended consequences.  But it is worth looking at -- it may even beat Stylish as a Thunderbird plugin